link url in ga4 report needs modification
In getting the outbound link and link text for some WordPress widgets that have graphics into a report, the link URL includes the html for the graphic such as img=src="pathtographic" and its width and its alt tag etc. I'd like to be able to programmatically screen out the unnecessary code in its reporting.
   ( see example). Is there a way to modify its text in the report? This is a looker report for the event scope.
Previously i had tried working with the tag manager using regex but it was a bit frustrating...
